# Nested Loop function taking minuets to run, anyway to improve efficiency?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, loops, jagged-arrays

I knew the function would include a lot of data processing, but I didn't think it would end up taking minuets to process.

The function in question is fed a jagged 2D array which is made up of Paragraphs > Sentences this is made from a text file fed by the user so can be massive. It takes this array and compares every sentence to each other and saves a score between each sentence which is the number of common words.

This takes forever and I honestly didn't think it would.

My main test text is only 181 sentences long, but this translates to 32.7 thousand values scored in a 2D array.

This matrix of values is then used to calculate and select the most "relevant" sentences from each paragraph, and other things.

The 181 sentence text takes 1min 15seconds to process, a text of only 70 sentences takes 35 seconds, but this is based on number of sentences not words, but it gives you an idea. I dread to think how long it would take on an actual document.

The function in question:

```
    protected void Intersection2DArray()
    {
        mainSentenceCoord = -1;
        for (int x1 = 0; x1 < results.Length; x1++)
        {
            for (int x2 = 0; x2 < results[x1].Length; x2++)
            {
                var mainSentencesWords = wordSplit(results[x1][x2]);
                secondarySentenceCoord = -1;
                mainSentenceCoord++;

                for (int y1 = 0; y1 < results.Length; y1++)
                {
                    for (int y2 = 0; y2 < results[y1].Length; y2++)
                    {
                        var secondarySentencesWords = wordSplit(results[y1][y2]);
                        int commonElements = mainSentencesWords.Intersect(secondarySentencesWords).ToList().Count();
                        secondarySentenceCoord++;
                        intersectionArray[mainSentenceCoord, secondarySentenceCoord] = commonElements;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The wordSplit function:

```
        protected List<String> wordSplit(string sentence)
        {
            var symbols = "£$€#&%+-.";
            var punctuationsChars = Enumerable.Range(char.MinValue, char.MaxValue - char.MinValue)
                                        .Select(i => (char)i)
                                        .Where(c => char.IsPunctuation(c))
                                        .Except(symbols)
                                        .ToArray();

            var words = sentence.Split(punctuationsChars)
                             .SelectMany(x => x.Split())
                             .Where(x => !(x.Length == 1 && symbols.Contains(x[0])))
                             .Distinct()
                             .ToList();
            return words;
        }
```

I initially wanted to do this split using one Regex line, but wouldn't figure it out, that may make it faster.

This loops through to select each sentence against each other, this is best I could come up. I'm fine with doing a total overall if it will drastically increase speed.

**Edit: Using Moby Disk suggestion heres my new instant code:**

Word Split function which is called once now and returns a List of List

```
    public List<List<string>> createWordList()
    {
        List<List<string>> wordList = new List<List<string>>();
        var symbols = "£$€#&%+-.";
        var punctuationsChars = Enumerable.Range(char.MinValue, char.MaxValue - char.MinValue)
                                    .Select(i => (char)i)
                                    .Where(c => char.IsPunctuation(c))
                                    .Except(symbols)
                                    .ToArray();

        for (int x1 = 0; x1 < results.Length; x1++)
        {
            for (int x2 = 0; x2 < results[x1].Length; x2++)
            {
                var words = results[x1][x2].Split(punctuationsChars)
                                            .SelectMany(x => x.Split())
                                            .Where(x => !(x.Length == 1 && symbols.Contains(x[0])))
                                            .Distinct()
                                            .ToList();
                wordList.Add(words);                    
            }
        }
        return wordList;
    }
```

And the now super slim Intersection Function

```
    protected void intersectionMatrix()
    {
        List<List<string>> wordList =  createWordList();
        mainSentenceCoord = -1;
        for (var x = 0; x < wordList.Count; x++)
        {
            secondarySentenceCoord = -1;
            mainSentenceCoord++;
            for (var y = 0; y < wordList.Count; y++)
            {
                secondarySentenceCoord++;
                intersectionArray[mainSentenceCoord, secondarySentenceCoord] = wordList[x].Intersect(wordList[y]).Count();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're basically comparing X sentences from one document with Y sentences from another, which will do a X*Y comparisons, and since each comparison in itself is a bit costly, yes, this will take time. Since you're doing common words, any chance you could preprocess one document into a dictionary keyed by word and work off of that?

Comment: Its comparing the sentences within the same document to each other, and then each sentence ends up with a score representing how it fairs against the others. Not sure if I explained well. I feel the issue with condensing the array, even if it were to then compare the array to the dictionary would be the scores need to be based off a sentence to sentence comparison which would be lost.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: So, the time it takes for 181 sentences based on a baseline for 70 sentences should be as you expect. In the 70 sentence case, you are doing 70*70 comparisons (4900). In the 181 case, you're doing 32761. 32761 / 4900 ~= 6.7. So, the 181 sentence case in the worst case should take 6.7x as long. Obviously, there is startup time and other fixed time costs that shouldn't be included.

Comment: I agree with Lasse V. Karlsen. Convert to HashSet and compare the them via a simple enumeration of one and .Contains() on the other. I realize paragraphs throw in some complexity but I'm sure you can make it work.

Comment: So since you must compare each and every sentence to each other, there is no way to optimize by reducing the number of comparisons (because the likelihood of there being duplicate sentences is so small that code to optimize such will end up consuming more time than you might gain). Instead, your best bet is to optimize your actual comparison. Not sure what wordSplit is doing - that's one place to potentially optimize. Another could be computing intersections. A third method will be to preprocess the sentences into a form that is much faster to compare.

Comment: For example, if you assigned each unique word a numerical value, then ran the comparisons on those values, rather than the words, I suspect that simple optimization would save you a good chunk of time (as your sentence count grows).

Comment: @iheanyi The wordSplit function splits the sentence into a list of unique words, then Intersect is used to return the number of common words between both lists. I feel this may be as or more efficient then having to go and assign each unique word a value, I've added the wordSplit function to my question, for the split I originally wanted to do it all using Regex, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @iheanyi I could apply the word -> number method at the jagged array level, however I need the sentences in full for review of them. I guess I could make each sentence value an array holding the sentence string and  a list holding the numbers representing each word, or something, but that would require looping through every sentences and word and checking if its unique etc, and now my head hurts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See update at the end:

There is some "low-hanging fruit" here that could speed it up a lot with out changing the algorithm itself:

1. wordSplit() recalculates "punctuationsChars" each time it is called.  Do that once up front.
2. You are calling wordSplit() for the same sentence a N^2 number of times instead of N number of times since it is in both the outer (x1,x2) loop and the inner (y1,y2) loop.  You only need to split 181 sentences, not 181^2 number of sentences.  So instead, loop through results, call wordSplit once on each sentence, and store that result.  If that takes up too much memory, look into memoization (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) although I think you should be okay since it will only result in about 1 more copy of the text.
3. You don't need the ToList() after the Intersect().  That creates a list you don't use.

I'm confused as to the values of mainSentenceCoord and secondarySentenceCoord.  What are the dimensions of the resulting intersectionArray?

**OMG!**  #1 is it!  That sped this up by a factor of 80x.  Look at this line:

```
Enumerable.Range(char.MinValue, char.MaxValue - char.MinValue)
```

char.MaxValue is 65536.  So if N=181, you are looping 181 x 181 x 65536!  I just ran the profiler to confirm it: 98.4% of the CPU time is spent in the ToArray() calls in wordSplit.

Comment: You;'re blowing my mind with the update I'm trying to get my head around it, as for the Coord variables and intersectionArray, thats a 2D array which holds the sentence number^2 so I can go and see the intersection value of any sentences, visualized its like one of those times table cards where you can go along and down to 3x5 etc. I need all these values as it allows me to do analysis such as common words within a paragraph or something. 

I'm trying to understand the eureka update you've added though in regards to where I'd place/replace

Comment: I'm not gonna pretend I understand what that "enumerable.range" line does/means, but I implemented all you're suggestions, and holy shi- its now instant. I've updated my question to show how I now have it, thank you!